# What is the largest number not expressible in the form $ax + by$ in at least $k$ ways?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a, b$ be positive integers and $x,y$ be nonnegative integers such that $a$ and $b$ have no common divisor greater than $1$.  If $N(k)$ is the largest number not expressible in the form $ax + by$ in at least $k$ ways, find $N(k).$

I tried using the fact about the Frobenius coin problem (that the largest number not expressible in the form $ax + by$ is $ab - a - b$), but it seems more complicated to prove at least. How should I go about finding $N(k)$?

Comment: I showed this to my friend who had studied numerical semigroups, and he said this: "It's very possible that this problem has no explicit general solution. For example for numerical semigroups with 4 or more generators, there's no known formula for the frobenius number in general. However nunerical semigroups generated by 2 elements have a lot more structure than others."

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee It's not just a lot more structure, the 2 element case is merely 1-dimensional and strikes me as very tractable.  For instance I would naively guess that the number of representations of $m\ge 0$ is always $1$ less than the number of representations of $m+ab$.

Comment: 'Not expressible in at least $k$ ways'? Could you explain what that means? Should it be 'expressible'?

Comment: @Dhruv Isn't "not expressible in $\ge k$ ways" synonymous with "expressible in $<k$ ways"?  What's unusual about the phrasing?

Comment: isnt a*a-a-b smaller ? regarding if a <b and a(a-1)>b

Comment: @Agawa001 Isn't $a^2-a-b$ smaller than what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Let $n\ge 0$ and let $r$ be the least nonnegative residue of $na^{-1}$ modulo $b$.  If $ax+by = n$ then $r \le x \le \lfloor n/a\rfloor$.
2. Define $R(n)$ to be the number of (nonnegative) solutions to $ax+by=n$.  Show that $R(n) = \lceil(\lfloor n/a\rfloor - r + 1)/b\rceil$.
3. Show that $R(n+ab) = R(n)$ for any $n\ge 0$.
4. Show that $N(k+1) = ab + N(k)$ for any $k \ge 1$.
5. You already know $N(1)$.  Now you know $N(k)$ for every $k$.

Comment: Can you explain steps 1 and 2?

Comment: For both 1 and 2 it's important to note that the equation $ax+by = n$ reduces to $ax \equiv n \pmod b$.  Since $a$ is invertible mod $b$, this uniquely determines $x \pmod b$.  So $x$ must be of the form $r + kb$ for some integer $k$: now figure out what the min and max values of $k$ could be.